# How to make voices louder in Black Mesa?

Tags: black-mesa

I'm playing Black Mesa. Since the resonance cascade, I keep meeting surviving scientists, who speak to me, but some I can barely hear them over the background noise. Is there any way to turn up the speech volume? I found an option to turn down the music volume, but other background noises remain.

Comment: I think voices are parts of sound effects, and their volume can only be controlled using that slider. Can you try opting in to a beta or other version, and see if it changes anything? Since there are very little similar complaints, it might be something on your side.